# Laravel makes log files with wrong owner

Tags: php, laravel

I use standard stack logging and created files has wrong owner. I need to have www-data owner, but files has root owner. How can I fix this? Laravel version is 5.8 under Apache2+Php.

Comment: This means you're running laravel as root.  You need to run it as `www-data`, and how you do that depends on your webserver.  If you're using `php artisan serve`, then just sudo to www-data first.

Comment: Laravel works under Apache2+Php

Comment: @МихаилТихонов What OS are you running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer was simple. I changed owner of **all directories** to ***www-data***. I do it early , but not for all directories.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the following file as root: `/etc/apache2/envvars`

using the command:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/envvars
```

change the user and group to yourself if there is only one user and you will never have permissions problems again.

I.E., if you are only logging in and running the server as user 'your_username':

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=your_username
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=your_username
```

Restart the server (if unsure, just reboot) and you are good to go.